# Ajax UpdatePanel no funciona al implementar en IIS8

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net, iis

Implementé un `UpdatePanel` en un *Webform* que necesito que se actualice automáticamente cada 30 segundos, cuando lo *debugeo* en Visual Studio 2013 funciona correctamente pero cuando lo implemento en mi servidor web con IIS8 no se actualiza. Ayúdenme a saber si necesito realizar alguna configuración en mi servidor IIS.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="3600" OnTick="Timer1_Tick1">
</asp:Timer>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <script runat="server">
            protected void Reload()
            {
                InitScreen();//inicializa controles de asp.net
                LoadData(); //carga informacion en conntroles del asp.net
            }
        </script>
               ///CODIGO HTML
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: yo usaba WAMSERVER o XAMPP ese error del ISS es comun por eso no lo uso para que no de tantos problemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta algunos de estos pasos:

1. Verifica si l página tiene algún error de Javascript.
2. Verifica la versión de ajax en el servidor y en el equipo local, debería ser la misma.
3. Copia la dll `System.Web.Extensions` que referencias en tu `web.config` en la aplicación local a tu servidor remoto en la carpeta `bin` de la aplicación.

También puedes revisar [esta página](http://blogs.visoftinc.com/2007/09/23/asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-not-working-common-problems/) para obtener mayor información al respecto.